# Has there been any discussion in the Catholic Church about whether hand sanitizer profanes the Host?

Tags: catholicism, communion, communion-hosts

Quite often, people use hand sanitizer before distributing the Host. Indeed, sometimes you can *taste* the hand sanitizer.

Has there been any discussion in the Catholic Church about whether this profanes the sacred species? As [St. Thomas Aquinas](https://www.vatican.va/news_services/liturgy/details/ns_lit_doc_20091117_comunione_en.html) says,

> [O]ut of reverence towards this Sacrament, nothing touches it, but
> what is consecrated; hence the corporal and the chalice are
> consecrated, and likewise the priest's hands, for touching this
> Sacrament. Hence, it is not lawful for anyone else to touch it except
> from necessity, for instance, if it were to fall upon the ground, or
> else in some other case of urgency.

Yet, here we have hand sanitizer touching the Sacrament. Should the hand sanitizer, at the least, be consecrated, as the chalice is?

Comment: I'd heard that in the Novus Ordo, everything used during Mass is instantly sacramentalized.  But in the Tridentine Rite everything needs to be consecrated individually.  So, swap out that bottle after Mass and you've got double a duty sanitizer.

Comment: If it were considered unfit usage at mass and thus profaning the Eucharist,  Rome would have said so by now. If there were serious discussion of such, some ***dubia*** would be in ecclesiastical papers.

Comment: @KenGraham The Catholic Church is not known for its speediness. ;) But perhaps there should be some discussion. It seems much more important to me than the issue of receiving the Host on the tongue or in the hand.

Answer (score 1):

Using hand sanitizer after the [*Lavabo*](https://www.liturgialatina.org/benedictine/holymass.htm#lavabo) is to introduce a new rite into the Mass. The *Lavabo* rite is described in the [*Ritus servandus in celebratione Missæ* (Rubrics of the Missale Romanum)](https://aomoi.net/odv/tlm/ritus_servandus_eng.htm) as, for the 1962 Missal:

> 6. With his hands joined before his breast, he goes to the Epistle side, and standing there, washes his hands as the minister pours the **water** [not hand sanitizer], i.e. the ends of his fingers with his thumbs and index fingers, saying meanwhile the psalm: *Lavabo inter innocentes manus meas*… etc. [[Ps. 25:6](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=21&ch=25&l=6-#x)ff.]

Or for the *Novus Ordo* ([*General Instruction of the Roman Missal*](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/ccdds/documents/rc_con_ccdds_doc_20030317_ordinamento-messale_en.html) 2003):

> 145. After the prayer *In spiritu humilitatis (Lord God, we ask you to receive
>      us)* or after the incensation, the priest washes his hands standing at the
>      side of the altar and, as the minister pours the **water**, says quietly, *Lava
>      me, Domine (Lord, wash away my iniquity).*

The introduction of new rites or changing them (e.g., substituting hand sanitizer for the water at the *Lavabo*) is forbidden by the [Council of Trent session 7, canon 13](https://ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2/creeds2.v.i.i.v.html#v.i.i.v-p3.59):

> Canon XIII.—**If any one saith, that the received and approved rites of the Catholic Church**, wont to be used in the solemn administration of the sacraments, **may** be contemned, or without sin be omitted at pleasure by the ministers, or **be changed**, by every pastor of the churches, **into other new ones**: **let him be anathema**.
>  <sub>Canon XIII.—***Si quis dixerit, receptos et approbates Ecclesiæ Catholicæ ritus**, in solemni sacramentorum administratione adhiberi consuetos, aut contemni, aut sine peccato a ministris pro libito omitti, aut **in novos alios** per quemcumque ecclesiarum pastorem **mutari posse**: **anathema sit**.*</sub>

Comment: What if the hand sanitizer is an addition to rather than a replacement of the water?